# Algorithm for getting symetric vertex sets of undirected graph

Tags: graphs, graph-isomorphism, transitivity

For my application problem, I am searching for **an algorithm that can find all symmetric vertex sets of an undirected labeled graph.**

My definition of symmetric vertex set is:
Let $G$ be a graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E = \{u,v\}, u,v \in V$. If $S \subseteq V$ and there exits an isomorphism $f$ on this graph such that for every $v\in S$, we have $f(v) \in S$, then $S$ is called a symmetric vertex set.

I have searched some graph matching algorithms, but have gotten no clue so far. I am wondering if any one can give me a hint, I will work on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to know the orbits of the action of the automorphism group of a graph on its vertices. This is equivalent to graph isomorphism, for which no really simple algorithms are known. Practical graph isomorphism algorithms, which work fast in practice, are known – check [nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) for example. Apparently nauty can compute the automorphism group directly, from which you can easily compute the orbits of its action on the vertices.

**Solving GI using your task.** Given *connected* graphs $G_1,G_2$, we want to know whether they are isomorphic. Compute the orbits, and check whether any of them mixes vertices from $G_1$ and $G_2$.

**Solving your task using GI.** Given a graph $G$ and two vertices $x,y$, create two copies of $G$ and attach a long path to $x$ in one of them and to $y$ in the other. The two vertices belong to the same orbit if these graphs are isomorphic.

The second reduction involves $n^2$ invocations of GI, whereas $\log B_n \approx n\log n$ (here $B_n$, the $n$th Bell number, is the number of partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$). This means that any reduction needs $\Omega(n\log n)$ invocations of GI, and suggests that my reduction can be improved.

Comment: Hello Yuval, thank you so much. I see that what I am looking for is "orbit"! I will do more research on this concept and nauty!